# Adding new method to ServiceEventSource disables logging (Service Fabric service)

Tags: azure-service-fabric, etw-eventsource

I am trying to add new method to ServiceEventSource class in a Service Fabric service (web app, web api or stateless services), to log warnings and exceptions  separately from information-type messages.

When I add new method to ServiceEventSource class, it does not output any message and this.IsEnabled() returns false. Out of the box, and if I remove newly added method, ServiceEventSource outputs messages as expected, and this.IsEnabled() returns true.

I am following [Using EventSource generically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-diagnostics-event-generation-app#using-eventsource-generically) sample. 
For example, just adding following code will cause ServiceEventSource to stop logging:

```
    private const int ErrorEventId = 7;
    [Event(ErrorEventId, Level = EventLevel.Error, Message = "Error: {0} - {1}")]
    public void Error(string error, string msg)
    {
        WriteEvent(ErrorEventId, error, msg);
    }
```

I've looked everywhere and can't find any reference to this unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Can you post the whole EventSource?

Comment: Have you checked if the new events does not conflict with the previous ones? Like name, EventID conflict? Also make sure whenever you change an existing method, you will have conflict with the old manifest.

Comment: Check the EventIds are unique...